# Pandas dataframe, get recent date in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to go through each row (iterrow?) and find the most recent date (sort function?) and put it in column 'G'

I'm having trouble combining the iterate function and the sorting function.

```
    A       B           C           D           E           F           G
0   1       20171018    20171019    20171001    20171002    id_123      
1   2       NaN         20171005    20171006    20171003    id_234      
2   3       NaN         NaN         20171019    20171020    id_345      
3   4       NaN         NaN         NaN         20171021    id_456
```

Desired Output

```
    A       B           C           D           E           F           G
0   1       20171018    20171019    20171001    20171002    id_123      20171019
1   2       NaN         20171005    20171006    20171003    id_234      20171006
2   3       NaN         NaN         20171019    20171020    id_345      20171020
3   4       NaN         NaN         NaN         20171021    id_456      20171021
```

Here is the code to generate the dataframe

```
data2 = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
        'B': ['20171018', '', '', ''], 
        'C': ['20171019', '20171005', '', ''],
        'D': ['20171001', '20171006', '20171019', ''],
        'E': ['20171002', '20171003', '20171020', '20171021'],
        'F': ['id_123','id_234','id_345','id_456'],
        'G': ['','','','']
        }
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

edit: I have already converted the date columns using datetime

Comment: are the date stored as datetime objects or as integers?

Comment: if you are downvoting me, please let me know why, or if my question is a duplicate

Comment: @James I converted the date columns using datetime, then I ran into this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.max()` method on the dataframe to get the most recent date.  You will need to pass the parameter `axis=1` to have it calculate the max along each row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'B': ['20171018', '', '', ''],
        'C': ['20171019', '20171005', '', ''],
        'D': ['20171001', '20171006', '20171019', ''],
        'E': ['20171002', '20171003', '20171020', '20171021'],
        'F': ['id_123','id_234','id_345','id_456']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to datetimes
for c in 'BCDE':
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c])

# create a new column
df['G'] = df[['B','C','D','E']].max(axis=1)
print(df)

   A          B          C          D          E       F          G
0  1 2017-10-18 2017-10-19 2017-10-01 2017-10-02  id_123 2017-10-19
1  2        NaT 2017-10-05 2017-10-06 2017-10-03  id_234 2017-10-06
2  3        NaT        NaT 2017-10-19 2017-10-20  id_345 2017-10-20
3  4        NaT        NaT        NaT 2017-10-21  id_456 2017-10-21
```

Comment: Thank you so much @James! I was trying to piece together a more complicated answer and I really appreciate the simplicity of yours. I'll incorporate those formatting details the next time I ask a question.